# Do we have to use quotations marks to stress the Russian words in a question in English?

Tags: discussion

Do we have to use quotations marks to stress the Russian words in a question in English?

Example:

> [What does мат  mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8714/what-does-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-mean)

Or

> What does "мат" mean?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it's still better to have them. Not all answers are in English, moreover, it is completely OK (and welcomed) to answer in Russian if it is more comfortable for both who asks and who asnwers.

So, visual designation is something we still need.

Comment: Well, I actually agree, but that doesn't answer the question. The question aims only at the typography in the English questions, and is not a motivation to ask in English.

Comment: it's better to hаve consistent set of rules applicable to questions and answers both in Russian and English.

Answer (score -1):

Since Russian uses Cyrillic, there is no need of adding these quotation marks. The different alphabets are enough for the reader to recognize what is the OP referring to.

Comment: Some russian words look like english even in cyrillic letters. Ссора, хор, ар etc. What does сор means?

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin Can you find a Russian word which can be confused with an English word? Ccopa, xop, ap do not lead to confusion. What do you mean with your question? Where is "cop"?